# exclusão de um objeto do banco com jpa 2 e jsf 2

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa

Bom estou tentando fazer uma exclusão utilizando jpa com jsf mas não estou tendo sucesso.
tenho minha tabela.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{mbProduto.produtos}"
            var="produtos"
            paginator="true"
            rows="10"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}
            {FirstPageLink}
            {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}
            {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}
            {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
            style="width: 80%"
            lazy="true">                
            <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Identificador
                    </f:facet>
                    #{produtos.idProduto}
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Nome
                    </f:facet>
                    #{produtos.nomeProduto}
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Especificações
                    </f:facet>
                    #{produtos.especificacaoProduto}
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Medida Horizontal
                    </f:facet>
                    #{produtos.medidaX}
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Medida Vertical
                    </f:facet>
                    #{produtos.medidaY}
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Preço de Venda
                    </f:facet>
                    #{produtos.precoDeMetroVenda}
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Ações" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:commandButton value="excluir"
                            action="#{mbProduto.excluir}"
                        id="produtos" ajax="false" onclick="if(!confirm('Deseja excluir #{produtos.nomeProduto}  ?')) return false" />
            </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

tenho minha Bean

```
public String excluir() {
    produtoDao.excluir(produto);
    return "pgproduto";
}
```

ela está como requestScoped

e finalmente tenho o metido na minha DAO

```
/*** excluir um produto */
public void excluir(Produto produto) {
    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(produto);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();     
}
```

agradeço e se alguém poder dar uma força fico grato

Comment: Qual erro esta obtendo? Esse objeto `produto` é o item selecionado, como ele esta sendo setado no seu Bean? Ja pensou em incluir o `var` produtos em sua action (`#{mbProdutos.excluir(produtos)}`)?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading

Answer (score 1):

Depois de pesquisar e claro com a ajuda do pessoal consegui uma resposta satisfatória a instancia do objeto precisa ser gerenciara e posso fazer isso com o metido merge ou find e também é interessante passar o objeto selecionado para o metido de exclusão e fiz isso com a tag`<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{produtos}" target="#{mbProduto.produto}"/>` acho que é só isso obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente ocorre erro porque o objeto `produto` está no estado `detached`, isto é, fora do  contexto do *Entity Manager*.

É importante saber que não se pode passar qualquer objeto para o JPA. Se aquela instância não está sendo gerenciada por ele, é considerada uma nova entidade.

O mais "seguro" neste caso é recuperar a instância de `produto` do `EntityManager` e depois solicitar a remoção.

Exemplo:

```
public void excluir(Produto produto) {
    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    //recupera a instância do EntityManager
    produto = em.find(Produto.class, produto.getId());

    em.remove(produto);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();     
}
```

Comment: fiz como você falou mas o erro continua estou colando algumas saídas do stactrace java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading    javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading

Comment: @AndreMartins Neste caso o erro é mais profundo. Parece que seu objeto não tem o ID preenchido. Verifique se ocorre isso mesmo fazendo a depuração (debug) do código e, se confirmado, revise o fluxo de informações para assegurar que os dados necessários estão sendo preenchidos. Caso contrário, adicione mais informações (como a pilha completa) editando sua pergunta, pois o espaço de comentários é limitado.

Comment: Se quiser dar uma olhada na aplicação
https://github.com/AndreMart/comunicaVisual

Comment: @AndreMartins Não tenho tempo para baixar o projeto, configurar todo o ambiente e depurá-lo. Se você não conseguir fazer isso por si mesmo, talvez mais tarde eu consiga dar uma olhada geral no código do projeto, mas não garanto pois estou bem atarefado essa semana.